# What's the fastest way to draw an image to the screen in JavaScript from array of RGB pixels?

Tags: javascript, performance, firefox, canvas

I'm working on a graphics frontend that renders server-side and pushes screen updates to a browser by sending compressed images to the client (think VNC). I've decided the overhead of encoding PNGs is too high, so currently I'm sending raw blobs of 8-bit RGB pixel values through a websocket (with compression enabled). This is actually very fast and I'm seeing great compression gains (75K -> 2.7k for example).

On the client however, I have to take the raw pixels and then draw them onto a canvas.  This is my current best code performance wise:

```
// receive message from server
self.ws.onmessage = function (evt) {
    // get image offset
    var dv = new DataView(evt.data);
    var dx = dv.getInt16(0);
    var dy = dv.getInt16(2);
    var ww = dv.getInt16(4);
    var hh = dv.getInt16(6);
    var offset = 8;

    // get context to canvas and create image
    var ctx = self.canvas.getContext("2d");
    var img = ctx.createImageData(ww, hh);

    // unpack image data
    var start = performance.now();
    var dst = 0, src = offset;
    for (var ii=0; ii < ww*hh; ii++) {
        img.data[dst++] = dv.getUint8(src++);
        img.data[dst++] = dv.getUint8(src++);
        img.data[dst++] = dv.getUint8(src++);
        img.data[dst++] = 255;
    }

    // draw image
    ctx.putImageData(img, dx, dy, 0, 0, ww, hh);
    var end = performance.now();

    console.log("draw took " + (end-start) + " milliseconds");
```

The aforementioned 75K image (which is 1000x500 pixels) takes ~53ms to render in this way though, which is a *long* time.  What's the fastest way to do this drawing operation?  I can output RGBA pixels instead of that makes life easier.

Edit: Seems like this might be more of a Firefox issue, Chrome runs this same decode loop in ~2.5ms on average.

Comment: Is the websocket server on the same machine as your web server? If it is, maybe you could have the websocket own a "temporary" folder in your site's files? That way, the websocket server would save the image to the temp folder, send the link to the client, and your web app can get the image directly without having to interpret it.

Comment: It is currently, but it's not a given.

Comment: What purpose exactly is the image for? Does the websocket generate it or is it something sent from another websocket client?

Comment: It's sent by the server, it's a piece of a rendered window.

Comment: Don't use your DataView anymore for setting the pixels data. Instead create an Uint8Array view, or even better if you can manage to have a fixed offset for your metadata, create an uint32Array for reading and one for setting from your imagedata.data.buffer so you have a single read write op per pixel.

Comment: Yes creating the ImageData directly from the buffer when available will probably even be faster. But please post this as an answer rather than just an edit to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switching to full RGBA output (which doesn't add much overhead thanks to the compression), and using this code to directly wrap the websocket buffer is significantly faster:

```
// receive message from server
self.ws.onmessage = function (evt) {
    // get image offset
    var dv = new DataView(evt.data);
    var dx = dv.getInt16(0);
    var dy = dv.getInt16(2);
    var ww = dv.getInt16(4);
    var hh = dv.getInt16(6);

    // get context to canvas and create image
    var ctx = self.canvas.getContext("2d");

    // draw image data
    var start = performance.now();
    ctx.putImageData(
        new ImageData(new Uint8ClampedArray(evt.data, 8), ww, hh),
        dx, dy,
        0,  0,
        ww, hh
    );
    var end = performance.now();

    console.log("draw took " + (end-start) + " milliseconds");
}
```

Now the large image size takes ~1ms to render in Firefox and 350us in Chrome.  Going to call that good enough.